# How to prevent an Async task function from running twice in the same time

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to prevent to call an async function from running twice in the same time.

I'm calling this function to populate a RecyclerView, and some times it happens that the function is called twice, and so I have duplicated items in the recycler view, so I want to prevent the function from running twice in the same time. is that possible ?

```
private class RefreshV2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
       //Start
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

     // Populate the recycler view
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       // finish
    }
}
```

I'm calling the task on OnResume

```
  @Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    RefreshV2 RVZ = new RefreshV2();
    RVZ.execute();
  Log.d("Resuming","yes");

}
```

and on Button ClickListener :

```
 RefreshV2 RVZ = new RefreshV2();
        RVZ.execute();
```

Comment: can you please post the code where you're executing this task

Answer (score 1):

You could add a global boolean variable which is set to true in the `onPreExecute()` and set to false in the `onPostExecute()`.
In the `doInBackground()` just check the state of that variable and decide whether to take actions or not!